# Keyboard beyond date picker

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uidatepicker

I'm trying to display a datepicker when you tap on a textfield. This all seems to be working fine but as soon as I dismiss the date picker it will show the keyboard instead.

So I basically have to dismiss it 2 times before it will actually disappear.

I've created a textfield class for the picker which looks the following

**EDIT MOVED ALL THE CODE INTO THE TEXTFIELD CLASS**

```
protocol TextFieldPickerDelegate {
    func pickerValueDidChange(date: Date, pickerMode: UIDatePickerMode, sender: TextFieldPicker)
}

public class TextFieldPicker: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var pickerMode: UIDatePickerMode = .date

    @IBInspectable var pickerType: String? {
        willSet {
            for s in (newValue?.lowercased().getStrings())! {
                switch s {
                case "date":
                    pickerMode = .date
                case "dateandtime":
                    pickerMode = .dateAndTime
                case "countdowntimer":
                    pickerMode = .countDownTimer
                case "time":
                    pickerMode = .time
                default:
                    pickerMode = .date
                }
            }
        }
        didSet {
            setupTextField()
        }
    }

    var textFieldPickerDelegate: TextFieldPickerDelegate?

    func setupTextField() {
        createPicker()
    }

    override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        delegate = self
    }

    override public func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect.zero
    }

    override public func shouldChangeText(in range: UITextRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    public func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func createPicker() {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = pickerMode
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerValueChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        let pickerToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
        pickerToolBar.tintColor = UIColor.gray
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("done", comment: ""), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(closePicker(_:)))
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        pickerToolBar.setItems([space, doneButton], animated: true)

        self.inputView = datePicker
        self.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar
    }

    func closePicker(_ sender: Any) {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func pickerValueChange(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        self.textFieldPickerDelegate?.pickerValueDidChange(date: sender.date, pickerMode: sender.datePickerMode, sender: self)
    }

    public func getDateString(date: Date, format: String) -> String {
        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return timeFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
}






// =================================================== OptionSet =================================================== \\
public struct PickerModes: OptionSet {
    private enum PickerMode: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
        case Date=1
        case DateAndTime=2
        case CountDownTimer=4
        case Time=8

        public var description: String {
            var shift = 0
            while (rawValue.hashValue >> shift != 1) { shift += 1 }
            return ["date", "dateandtime", "countdowntimer", "time"][shift]
        }
    }
    public let rawValue: Int
    public init(rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }
    private init(_ mode: PickerMode) { self.rawValue = mode.rawValue }

    static let Date = PickerModes(PickerMode.Date)
    static let DateAndTime = PickerModes(PickerMode.DateAndTime)
    static let CountDownTimer = PickerModes(PickerMode.CountDownTimer)
    static let Time = PickerModes(PickerMode.Time)
}

extension String {
    func getStrings() -> [String] {
        var stringArray: [String] = []
        let strings = self.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)
        for s in strings {
            let string = s.removeSpaces()
            stringArray.append(string)
        }
        return stringArray
    }

    func removeSpaces() -> String {
        if self.characters.first == " " {
            var copy = self
            copy.characters.removeFirst()
            return copy.removeSpaces()
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

This class is entirely responsible for showing the date picker and dealing with displaying the correct type of date picker in case there are multiple different pickers needed in one screen.

**EDIT 2**
If anyone else tries my code it will work fine without any problems. The issue I was having is that I accidentally set my custom class to a `UIView` that contained my `UITextField` so when I tapped the textfield it would first trigger the keyboard for the `UIView` and then the `UIDatePicker` so when the `UIDatePicker` was resigned the keyboard would still be there.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing some research and it seems to me that there are much easier methods of creating a date picker inside a text field. You could just use one of them. `https://blog.apoorvmote.com/change-textfield-input-to-datepicker/`

Comment: did you add it in both or try each individually

Comment: @NoSixties  what happens

Comment: First individually and then on both but didn't do anything for it

Comment: @NoSixties is your create date picker method called whenver the date picker is called, if not when is it called

Comment: create date picker gets called when the view loads

Comment: @NoSixties Can you add your functions that call the date picker

Comment: I'll do you one better. I'll edit my answer. I changed my code around so everything lives in the uitextfield extended class

Comment: @NoSixties where is your code that calls the date picker. That is what I am looking for, also does and first responder work

Comment: there is no code that calls the date picker man. you attach the date picker to the textfields `inputview` that is where the datepicker gets connected to the view that normally displays the keyboard. If you would copy the entire class into a project of your own and assign it to a textfield it would work for you

Comment: @NoSixties I have been looking at a bunch of UIDatefield in text field examples and they have used a different approach such as this one. [Example](https://blog.apoorvmote.com/change-textfield-input-to-datepicker/). They seem more intuitive than your method and a lot simpler I was just asking that because they all use a calling method.

Comment: I just fixed it I accidentally set my custom class to the view containing the textfield. Which was causing the keyboard to show up twice.

I did see a lot of examples for it as well and I don't agree with you on how it is simpler or more intuitive at all. Those methods create the `date picker` every single time you tap the view. where mine gets created when the textfield is being drawn and after that it doesn't created it again unless the entire view is reloaded

Comment: my way is probably a bit more complicated yes but it's also more generic and it only needs to use the delegate method in the view controller where all the examples need code for each view and view controller you want to have a date picker in.